# How to align a set of divs to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-float

How to move the block of divs to a) center and b) right ?
That is, i wish to move the innerWrap and its contents to either center or right.

[image]

```css
.smallW {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}

.largeW {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

.outerWrap {
  position: relative;
}

.innerWrap {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerWrap">
  <div class="innerWrap">
    &nbsp;
    <div class="smallW"></div>
    <div class="largeW"></div>
    <div class="smallW"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/prideaux/n0cadsvh)

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered it, but i can only accept one. All the answers provided thus far use flex, i wonder how it would be done in the days prior to flex...

Comment: first rule to center : Never use float. Easiest way than flexbox is to consider inline-block then simply adjust text-align

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.innerWrap{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row
 justify-content: center
}
```

you can use below for right align

```
justify-content: flex-end
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was first and it works, so I am taking it. I got confused by center(flex-end).. So for anyone that needs this answer, you would write it separately as justify-content: center OR justify-content: flex-end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: flex` for this. It's much easier to get alignment done that using `float`.

With the use of flex you can align your inner elements to the center by using `justify-content: center;` or to the end of the container by using `justify-content: flex-end;` so you don't need to use `float` property. This is a sample code. Hope it helps you.

HTML

```
<div class="outerWrap">
  <div class="innerWrap">
    <div class="smallW"></div>
    <div class="largeW"></div>
    <div class="smallW"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.smallW {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.largeW {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.outerWrap {
  display: flex;
}

.innerWrap {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;/* For center align */
  /* justify-content: flex-end;  */ /* Align to end */
}
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/o7e4cjdL/

Answer (score 0):

You can align the contents using `flexbox` in innerWrap

```
.innerWrap.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.innerWrap.right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c31vdwup/)**

```css
.smallW {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
}

.largeW {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}


.outerWrap {
  position:relative;
}

.innerWrap {
  background-color:yellow;
  width:100%;
}

/* additional styles */
.innerWrap.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.innerWrap.right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerWrap">
    <div class="innerWrap center">
        &nbsp;
        <div class="smallW"></div>
        <div class="largeW"></div>
        <div class="smallW"></div>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <div class="innerWrap right">
        &nbsp;
        <div class="smallW"></div>
        <div class="largeW"></div>
        <div class="smallW"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.smallW {
    flex-basis: 10%;
    background-color: green;  
}

.largeW {
    flex-basis: 50%; 
    background-color:blue;  
}

.innerWrap {
  background-color:yellow;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerWrap">
    <div class="innerWrap">
        &nbsp;
        <div class="smallW"></div>
        <div class="largeW"></div>
        <div class="smallW"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use Flex instead of float.